# Webcam video in Flash has horizontal bars disturbance

Tags: video, flash, webcam

I created a webcam recorder in flash, but about 10-20% of people have this bars on video:

[image]

How to get rid of that bars ? I tried to create .swf with lot of different settings and target flash player version. As you can see those bars doesn't seem to be compressed, so maybe this is the player issue, not recorder ?

Comment: Which player you are using to play the video file?

Comment: Please explain more about this webcam recorder in flash.

Comment: I had something similar in Python, for me it was due to the recorder trying to record at too high of a framerate (and then again when I was trying to save it).  Not sure if that will have any bearing for you, but I figured it would be worth mentioning if it could help at all.